# setting display attribute to none removes href target

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I came across this problem when building a Shiny application in R. In the application, an action button is used to trigger a hidden download button. This would allow me to observe the action button event, react to that event, and then trigger the download process.

However, when I set the display attribute of the download button to hidden the href target of the button, which typically targets something like `"session/1c47..ef8/download/download_show?w="`, was missing.

Below is a smaller Shiny application which reproduces the problem.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML(".hide { display: none; }")),
      tags$script(HTML('
        Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("trigger-button", function(message) {
          document.getElementById(message.button_id).click();
        });
      '))
    ),
    div(
      class = "disable",
      downloadButton("download_shown", "Shown"),
      div(
        class = "hide",
        downloadButton("download_hidden", "Hidden")
      )
    ),
    br(),
    actionButton("trigger_shown", "I can trigger the visible button!"),
    actionButton("trigger_hidden", "I can trigger the hidden button!")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$download_shown <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "sample.txt",
      content = function(file) {
        cat("I'm visible!\n", file = file)
      }
    )

    output$download_hidden <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "sample2.txt",
      content = function(file) {
        cat("I'm hidden!\n", file = file)
      }
    )

    observeEvent(input$trigger_shown, {
      session$sendCustomMessage(
        "trigger-button",
        list(button_id = "download_shown")
      )
    })

    observeEvent(input$trigger_hidden, {
      session$sendCustomMessage(
        "trigger-button",
        list(button_id = "download_hidden")
      )
    })
  }
)
```

In the application, the two action buttons trigger their corresponding download button. Triggering the visible download button causes a correct download of the file `sample.txt`. Triggering the hidden download button causes a download of an HTML file, the webpage, instead of the `sample2.txt` file. Furthermore, if you inspect the HTML generated you can see that the `download_hidden` download button has an href attribute with no target.

- Is there anything in the HTML spec that dictates a hidden element
  cannot have an href target? This seems highly unlikely and none of my
  searching has turned up any -one or -thing confirming this.
- Internally does Shiny ignore elements which are hidden?
- In the mean time, does anyone have a suggestion for hiding the button
  without using `hidden` or `display: none;`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have discovered the solution thanks to this [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/126) over on GitHub.

Shiny, by default, suspends objects which are hidden. So, by hiding a `downloadButton` the corresponding `downloadHandler` is suspended. I am still unsure how Shiny uses `downloadHandler` to register a download, **but** however the process works, it is not triggered if, as I said, the corresponding `downloadButton` is hidden.

The solution is to use the `outputOptions` function provided by Shiny. From the help page for `outputOptions`,

> suspendWhenHidden, when TRUE (the default), the output object will be suspended (not execute) when it is hidden on the web page. When FALSE, the output object will not suspend when hidden, and if it was already hidden and suspended, then it will resume immediately.

By specifying `suspendWhenHidden = FALSE` after defining the `downloadHandler` we can prevent the href problem described in the original question.

Below is a revised, working version of the small Shiny application included in the original question.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML(".hide { display: none; }")),
      tags$script(HTML('
        Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("trigger-button", function(message) {
          document.getElementById(message.button_id).click();
        });
      '))
    ),
    div(
      class = "disable",
      downloadButton("download_shown", "Shown"),
      div(
        class = "hide",
        downloadButton("download_hidden", "Hidden")
      )
    ),
    br(),
    actionButton("trigger_shown", "I can trigger the visible button!"),
    actionButton("trigger_hidden", "I can trigger the hidden button!")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$download_shown <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "sample.txt",
      content = function(file) {
        cat("I'm visible!\n", file = file)
      }
    )
    outputOptions(output, "download_shown", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

    output$download_hidden <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "sample2.txt",
      content = function(file) {
        cat("I'm hidden!\n", file = file)
      }
    )
    outputOptions(output, "download_hidden", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

    observeEvent(input$trigger_shown, {
      session$sendCustomMessage(
        "trigger-button",
        list(button_id = "download_shown")
      )
    })

    observeEvent(input$trigger_hidden, {
      session$sendCustomMessage(
        "trigger-button",
        list(button_id = "download_hidden")
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Remember to place calls to `outputOptions` after assigning corresponding reactive expressions to `output`, otherwise `outputOptions` will raise an error.

Answer (score 2):

`display:none;` causes any element to be *not rendered*. Therefore, it will not take any space in the document. Therefore, it will not receive any (real) `pointer-events`.

I would not even count on its ability to receive programmatically triggered pointer events, as I expect at least a few major browsers to interfere, in the name of *general browsing safety principles*.

If you want your element to be a valid target for user interaction (real or programmatic), I suggest using...

```
opacity: .01;
```

...on it. This way it will be rendered. If you don't want it to occupy any space in the content flow, consider applying `position:absolute` to it.